# SonarQube issue status updation for external issues

Tags: sonarqube, pmd, sonarlint, sonarscanner

I have issues reported for my project through PMD analysis and am allowing sonarqube to consume the report through external properties.
Now I can see the external issues in sonar UI, but am not able to change the issue status from open to confirmed…there is no dropdown available.
I am using SonarQube 8.5.1 version.

Could someone help how will be able to change the issue status for these?

Answer (score 0):

see [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/generic-issue/)

> There are a couple of limitations with importing external issues:
>
> - you can't manage them within SonarQube; for instance, there is no ability to mark them False Positive.
> - you can't manage the activation of the rules that raise these issues within SonarQube. External rules aren't visible on the Rules page or reflected in Quality Profiles.